# How to use ng-model / $scope with Angular Factory and Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, scope, factory

```
// SERVICES
app.factory('searchFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.post("/api", { tag: "food" });
}]);

// CONTROLLERS
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'searchFactory', function ($scope, searchFactory) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
      searchFactory.then(function(response) {
        $scope.recipeData = JSON.parse(response.data);
      });
    };

// HTML
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="recipeTag" class="form-control" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Find Recipes" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

Does anyone know how I can use $scope.recipeTag from ng-model to replace "food" in the factory? I need to be able to pass the form input as a parameter into the factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a funtion that expects a parameter in your factory.

Example:

```
            var factory= {
                post: function(customTag) {
                    return $http.post("/api", { tag: customTag });
                }
            };
            return factory;
```

Comment: it says service is undefined. also how would i call it in the controller?

Comment: My bad, I named it factory instead of service... it needs to 'return factory'.

Comment: In the controller, using Angular's Dependency Injection you can inject your searchFactory, and then you could do something like searchFactory.post(customTagGoesHere)